# Stop an Action Script at end of scene in Flash (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am new to action script and i am having a few problems.

I have created a movie in Flash CC with 8 scenes.  Scene 6 has an action script that randomly places birds which fly across the screen.  Scene 7 has an almost identical script which does the same thing only slower (using a different symbol) and with a couple of variables changed.

The first problem surfaced when testing the movie with the action script only placed in scene 6, it simply did not end at the end of scene 6 and proceeded to play through scene 7 and scene 8.

When adding the script to scene 7, it breaks completely.  Testing the individual scenes work fine but when testing the whole movie nothing happens and I get errors.

Here is the action script I am using:

**Scene 6**

```
import flash.utils.Timer;

var timer: Timer = new Timer(100, 45);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerF);
timer.start();

function timerF(event: TimerEvent): void {
    var mcClip: Bird = new Bird();
    var yVal:Number = (Math.ceil(Math.random()*200));
    mcClip.x = -20;
    mcClip.y = yVal;
    addChildAt(mcClip,10);
}
```

**Scene 7**

```
import flash.utils.Timer;

var timer: Timer = new Timer(100, 40);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerF);
timer.start();

function timerF(event: TimerEvent): void {
    var mcClip: Bird2 = new Bird2();
    var yVal:Number = (Math.ceil(Math.random()*400));
    mcClip.x = 0;
    mcClip.y = yVal;
    addChildAt(mcClip,3);
}
```

These are the errors I get:

```
Scene 7 (Birds), Layer 'Bird Action Script', Frame 1114, Line 3, Column 5
1151: A conflict exists with definition timer in namespace internal.
```

and

```
Scene 7 (Birds), Layer 'Bird Action Script', Frame 1114, Line 7, Column 10
1021: Duplicate function definition.
```

I need to stop the script at the end of each scene, but I don't know how.  I have searched Google and cannot find anything helpful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before scene 6 finishes you need to remove the Timer event listener, stop the timer and maybe even nullify it, ie:

```
timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerF);
timer.stop();
timer = null;
```

If you're using the timeline, the error issues might be if the frame that 'contains' the actionscript for scene 6 might be carrying on into scene 7. Placing an empty keyframe on that layer before the end of the scene might help.

EDIT - in response to new comments below:

Before the line defining your timer, add:

```
var _birds:Array = new Array();
```

Then, in your TimerEvent handler:

```
function timerF(event: TimerEvent): void {
    _birds.push(new Bird());
    var yVal:Number = (Math.ceil(Math.random()*200));
    _birds[_birds.length-1].x = -20;
    _birds[_birds.length-1].y = yVal;
    addChildAt(_birds[_birds.length-1], 10);
}
```

Then, at the end of your scene:

```
stop();
timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerF);
timer.stop();
timer = null;
for (var loop:int=0;loop<_birds.length;loop++) {
    removeChild(_birds[loop]);    
}
_birds.length = 0;
// additional code here to go to next scene?
```

Obviously the timer variable names should change to match the names you're now using in each scene.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately this did not solve the problem.  It does not appear to have made any difference.  I added it in the last frame of the scene.  I also tried adding a blank frame at the end and the error's remain the same.

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of hoping against hope that you weren't actually using separate scenes, but it seems like you are. Sorry to avoid your question, but do you NEED to be using the timeline? I know you said you were new to actionscript, but I'd HIGHLY recommend using external classes as opposed to the timeline. It's a much more flexible and dynamic way of working - and more intuitive once you know how.

Comment: Yes, somebody else has told me the same thing regarding external classes and I will most certainly be working with them in the near future (next project maybe?!)  However right now, I need this to be in the timeline.  I am at the end of this project and I just need to get this action script working and add a few more sounds to wrap it up.

Comment: OK, i have managed to get rid of the errors and now the birds show in the movie (both scenes) by renaming "timer" to "timerb", "timerF" to "timerFb" and "yVal" to "yValb" in the script on the 7th scene.  However, the birds do not stop at the end of scene 6 and carry on into scene 7, where they are joined by the birds from that scene.  They both carry on into scene 8.  I just need to stop the birds at the end of their respected scene now.

Comment: Instead of using a local variable in your bird-creation code (the Timer event handler) you should define a '_birds' Array earlier in your code and, in the handler, 'push' each new bird into that. The reason to do that is so that, at the end of your scene, you will still have an accessible reference to each bird which you can use to remove them from the stage (ie, removeChild(_birds[0]), removeChild(_birds[1]) and so on). You can then also loop through them to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

> need to stop the script at the end of each scene

Simply place `stop();` in the last frame of the scene.
Select last frame of the scene, hotkey `F9` will open window with actions.

[image: Action window]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  This was the first thing I tried and it does not work.

Comment: Actually, It works. So you have some specific in your project that have impact on scenes' playback, or you don't do it in the main timeline of the scene.

Comment: Sorry, I am unsure of what you are saying here.  I added the stop(); in the last frame of the scene and it does not work for me.

Comment: After fixing the errors I was getting, the movie is working as it should apart from the birds not stopping.  Using stop(); now freezes the timeline but the script continues to run on a static background.  I do not want to stop the timeline, just the action script (i.e. the "birds").